# Why Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault() is null?

Tags: xconnect

Why Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault() is null in incognito mode of browser. I applied the following code but still same.

```
    public void LoadContact(Guid customIdentifier)
    {
        var manager = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager;

        if (manager != null)
        {
            using (var client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew)
                    {
                        Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
                        manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(AnalyticsHelpers.CurrentTracker.Contact);
                    }

                    var identifier = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault();

                    if (identifier != null)
                    {
                        var reference = new IdentifiedContactReference(identifier.Source, customIdentifier.ToString("N"));

                        var existingContact = client.Get<Contact>(reference,
                            new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey));

                        var contact = client.Get(
                            new IdentifiedContactReference(identifier.Source, identifier.Identifier),
                            new ContactExpandOptions(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey));

                        client.MergeContacts(existingContact, contact);

                        client.Submit();
                    }
                }
                catch (XdbExecutionException e)
                {
                    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(e.Message, e, "LoadContact");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I cannot `IdentifyAs(...)` here which will generate the id.

I reloaded the page few times, but nothing happens. I am using **Sitecore 9.0.1**. I checked the cookie, **the analytics cookie is there**. The contact is also not null. I am **not making any async call**. It is a normal page load.

Comment: If you use a normal browser, does the contact being identified? Normally, Sitecore make use of the analytics cookie. So, if the cookie is not created, Sitecore won't be able to identify the user. Please check if the `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` cookie is created on private browser

Comment: Specify please version of Sitecore. Is it only happening in Incognito mode?

Comment: @peter-prochazka yes, incognito mode. But I think you might be able to reproduce it if you clear cookie from browser. I found this issue also happening for another developer in my team.

Comment: Could you post here also surrounding code maybe whole method to get picture what you are trying to achieve? I can then try and debug code on my machine. Do you have anonymous contacts?

Comment: @peter-prochazka yes I have anonymous contacts. It happens very often that's why I cannot ignore. It will cause contact merging failure. I will post the code when I am in office.

Comment: To fix this you need to enable indexing of anonymous contacts IMHO. Take a look here https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/index.html and here https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/enable-anonymous-contact-indexing.html . Enable it and try it once again.

Comment: @peter-prochazka , I re-indexed, didn't work. I added some code sample with question.

Comment: I think you are breaking some design principles and patterns at first place. You have LoadContact method which is effectively creating contact. I wouldn't expect that. Rename method

Comment: to your question - try to use CreateContact method instead SaveContactToColletionDB. See these articles https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-contacts/contactmanager-reference.html#createcontact-notnull-id-id and https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/xconnect-client-api-overview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @peter-prochazka for showing me the way. Here is my working code:

```
var manager = AnalyticsHelpers.GetContactManager();

if (manager != null)
{
    using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
    {

        var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference(
            Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource,
            Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"));

        var contact = client.Get<Contact>(trackerIdentifier,
            new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions());

        if (contact == null)
        {
            manager.CreateContact(ID.NewID);
        }

        if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew)
        {
            Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
            manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact);
        }
    }
}
```